# API Version in Salesforce

Tags: api

My Org has a lot of code written on API 13-18. The current API version is 40/41. What are the possible impacts this org can foresee in near future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may happen that, some of the features from new release doesn't support the classes & pages of old API version and even some updated API's doesn't support the old API versions of Classes & pages. At that time, you will have to change the API version of the class.